# why my iOS11 navigationController doesn't to work

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

I only want to show a **large title**.
My `ViewController.swift` look like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        title = "Hello world"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Is your ViewController in a navigation controller ?

Comment: Sorry, how to make my ViewController in a navigation controller?

Comment: If you don't know how to insert a view controller as the root controller or to simply push a view controller on a navigation controllers stack. You should go back and do some research. It sounds like you don't even know the basics of UINavigationControllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to show large title in navigationbar you need to make `largeTitleDisplayMode` `.always` add below lines of code into your `viewDidLoad` also don't forget to check **ios11** **or not**

```
   title = "Hello world"

   if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    }
```

and your `UIViewController` should have a `UINavigationController`
If your UIViewController not embed in UINavigationController do the following steps

**Open your storyboard -> select your view controller -> Editor -> Embed In -> NavigationController**

Comment: It doesn't display anything still. It is worth mentioning that I clone project from other people. It works. I have the same code for that project but doesn't work still. It's so bad.

Comment: have you present this viewcontroller view `navigationController`

Comment: Im pretty sure just checking if iOS 11 isn't enough. You should also check if the system responds to the method also

Comment: Yes! It works. Thank you very much. @Ganesh Manickam

Answer (score 0):

```
  let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 60))
        navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 145.0/255.0, blue: 245.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        
        self.navigationItem.title = "Add Title"
        self.view .addSubview(navigationBar)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I try to add this code.But it doesn't work and only show a full white screen.

Comment: @sunny check now

Comment: It only shows a very narrow react have some blue without any text.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure your `ViewController` is inside a `UINavigationController`.

Proceed to check for IOS 11

```
title = "Title
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

} else { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. How to make my ViewController is inside a UINavigationController?

Comment: you can create it programatically:  `UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you need to add your **viewcontroller** in a **navigation controller**

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let mainController = ViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainController)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```